# Swear or not swear?

Tags: matthew, contradiction, deuteronomy, james

In Deuteronomy 10:20 (NASB)

> You shall fear the Lord your God; you shall serve Him, and cling to Him, and **you shall swear by His name**.

In Matthew 5:34-37

> 34 But I say unto you, **Swear not at all**; neither by heaven; for it is God's throne:
>
> 35 Nor by the earth; for it is his footstool: neither by Jerusalem; for it is the city of the great King.
>
> 36 Neither shalt thou swear by thy head, because thou canst not make one hair white or black.
>
> 37 But let your communication be, Yea, yea; Nay, nay: for whatsoever is more than these cometh of evil.

In James 5:12 (NASB)

> But above all, my brothers and sisters, **do not swear**, either by heaven or by earth or with any other oath; but your yes is to be yes, and your no, no, so that you do not fall under judgment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest well-known explanation here is offered by the summary of Ellicott -

> (34) Swear not at all.—Not a few interpreters, and even whole
> Christian communities, as e.g. the Society of Friends, see in these
> words, and in James 5:12, a formal prohibition of all oaths, either
> promissory or evidential, and look on the general practice of
> Christians, and the formal teaching of the Church of England in her
> Articles (Art. xxxix.), as simply an acquiescence in evil. The first
> impression made by the words is indeed so strongly in their favour
> that the scruples of such men ought to be dealt with (as English
> legislation has at last dealt with them) with great tenderness. Their
> conclusion is, however, it is believed, mistaken:
>
> 1. Because, were it true, then in this instance our Lord would be directly repealing part of the moral law given by Moses, instead of
>    completing and expanding it, as in the case of the Sixth and Seventh
>    Commandments. He would be destroying, not fulfilling.
> 2. Because our Lord himself answered, when He had before been silent, to a solemn formal adjuration (Matthew 26:63-64), and St. Paul
>    repeatedly uses such forms of attestation (Romans 1:9; 1Corinthians
>    15:31; 2Corinthians 1:23; Galatians 1:20; Philippians 1:8).
> 3. Because the context shows that the sin which our Lord condemned was the light use of oaths in common speech, and with no real thought
>    as to their meaning. Such oaths practically involved irreverence, and
>    were therefore inconsistent with the fear of God.
>
> The real purpose of an oath is to intensify that fear by bringing the
> thought of God’s presence home to men at the very time they take them,
> and they are therefore rightly used when they attain that end.
> Practically, it must be admitted that the needless multiplication of
> oaths, both evidential and promissory, on trivial occasions, has
> tended, and still tends, to weaken awe and impair men’s reverence for
> truth, and we may rejoice when their number is diminished. In an ideal
> Christian society no oaths would be needed, for every word would be
> spoken as by those who knew that the Eternal Judge was hearing them.